# LINQ inside a Select LINQ - Will it have a performance issue?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, query-performance

I want to query a list of person from the database and in the table, it has a column that also contains a list of relatives which is another table in the database. Will this line of code solve the problem? Will it produce a performance issue in the future with thousands of data?

Refer to the code below:

```
 public class Employee
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }   
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public virtual List<Relatives> { get; set; }
 }

 public class Relatives
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }   
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
 }

var list = GetDbSet<Employee>().Select(x => new
  {
  id = x.Id,
  name = x.Name,
  ListOfRelatives = string.Join(",", (x.Relatives.Where(y => y.EmployeeId == x.Id).Select(z => z.Name)))
  }.ToList();
```

If this it not the best solution, is there other way to solve this problem?

Comment: as long as it is index based and good it won't have any issues with performance. I have experience with such LINQs as you defind above in an old live products and they work fine.

Comment: What is `list`?  You're asking about performance, but you haven't mentioned with LINQ provider you're using here.  LINQ-to-Objects?  LINQ-to-Entities?  Something else?

Comment: @Yuck sorry I forgot to mention. It's a LINQ-to-Entities.

Comment: @ARr0w is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: @JPDolocanog If it's LINQ to Entities please show the definitions of entities and query with context (here I see list)

Comment: @arekzyla I provided a more detailed code.

Comment: I will suggest to break down your query into two part . . why are requesting server two times . x.Relatives.Where(y => y.EmployeeId == x.Id).Select(z => z.Name)) .. Get one time all relative keep into local variable , fetch from it.